# using float number with is operator in python

Tags: python, floating

when I give two float numbers, it shows false, why? it should be true. why it shows false?

[image]

Comment: You want to check `a == b`? Read more about `is` vs `==` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/8353711)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: the only 2 situations where you should use `is` operator is when 1. you are comparing if two objects share the same memory location 2. comparing things with `None` explicitly to avoid type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The “is keyword” is used to test whether two variables belong to the same object, i.e. if they are referring to the same memory location.

So `a is b` is `False` and `a == b` is `True`.

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-keyword-in-python/) might help.

Answer (score 3):

It shows false because both variables are not sharing the same memory location. For more, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/8353711).

How to check this?

```
a = 8.5
b = 8.5
print(id(a), id(b)) # 140035857364400 140035857418800
print(a is b) # False
print(a == b) # True
```